# Verb or adjective for "working carefully on something for a lot of time"

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word (verb or adjective) to describe the process of working on something carefully for a lot of time. It should probably be something close to "ponder", but related to working process, not thinking.

**Example:**
I have been working on this project for a lot of time and it's finally done.

Here either the phrase **working for a lot of time** should be replaced with a verb.
Or **for a lot of time** should be replaced with an adverb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you, great extentions to the answers in this post, they complement each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assiduously seems like a perfect fit.

> [**Assiduously**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assiduously) - Adjective:
>
> constant in application or effort; working diligently at a task; persevering; industrious; attentive.

Showing great care and perseverance.

I have been working on this project *assiduously* and it's finally done.

Comment: 2 words in answer, actually! Persevere could also be used. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Labor**   (UK:  **Labour**)
verb

> work hard; make great effort.

examples:
*‘And like Mr Sherry, Mr Hillier has **laboured** for many years and has likewise produced three heavy volumes, the last of which is about to see the light of day in the bookshops.’*

*‘Suppose that one worker **labors** for five consecutive years to produce one such engine.’*

*‘Each **labored** many years as an attorney before moving to the front office.’*

^ [from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/labour)

> to exert one's powers of body or mind especially with painful or strenuous effort

examples:
*'He **labored** for several years as a miner.'*

*'I have been **laboring** through this book for months.'*

*'She has **labored** in vain to convince them to accept her proposal.'*

^ [from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/labor)

Comment: The word "labor" seems to be referring to the kind of work that a person does not like and although I did not specify it in the post, I was more inclined to find the opposite, meaning "the work that a person enjoys, but where they work carefully and for a lot of time". But anyway, good words, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

**Tirelessly** (Adverb)

```
Meaning : with great effort or energy.
example : "He worked tirelessly to promote environmental awareness"
```

Using "tirelessly" however, won't convey that the work was carefully done.

Comment: Yes, "tirelessly" is probably not the best word. Appreciate your help, though!